# Which spider(?) is this hanging out on my seaside daisy?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

The title says it all... location: Switzerland

[image]

Comment: These things are very shy (of humans, anyway), but great ambush hunters.  I watched one wait patiently on one side while a hoverfly explored the (comparatively) vast surface on the other side of a gaillardia, until the hoverfly chanced within range of the crab spider, whereupon it pounced with great rapidity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Misumena vatia.** (Crab spider, *female specimen*.)

[image: Fat bottomed poser, looks like a crab on a flower.]

<sup>OZGUR KEREM BULUR / [SCIENCE PHOTO LIBRARY](https://www.sciencephoto.com/media/1022350/view/flower-crab-spider) 2022, fair usage.</sup>

Size: Females can reach 1 cm at maturity, males half that size.

Comprising more than 2000 species, crab spiders can be found all over the world, with the Mitsumena Vatia being confined exclusively to Europe and North America.

A kind of active camouflage allows them to change colour with each moult in response to their surroundings. Colours and intensity of marking varies, the body being yellow or white, the markings pale through intense red and green.

Females are mostly static and wait to catch prey on flowers, trailing a silken line which the males follow to find them.